# Extract the string matched in a regex, not the line, with awk

Tags: regex, awk

This should not be too difficult but I could not find a solution.

I have a HTML file, and I want to extract all URLs with a specific pattern.

The pattern is `/users/<USERNAME>/` - I actually only need the USERNAME.

I got only to this:

```
awk '/users\/.*\//{print $0}' file
```

But this filters me the complete line. I don't want the line.

Even just the whole URL is fine (e.g. get `/users/USERNAME/`), but I really only need the USERNAME....

Comment: Maybe just `awk -F'/' '{print $3}'  file` will do?

Comment: why `awk`, you can use `grep -Eo '/users/[^[:blank:]]+' file`

Comment: 1. Because I don't know `grep` well enough even if I use it a lot
2. Because I wanted to be smart and try something new
3. It works pretty well, actually it gives me `/users/USERNAME/blabla` because I did not clarily that the patterrn indeed is `/users/USERNAME/blabla/`

Comment: If you add sample input with expected output then it would be easier to provide a good solution.

Comment: `grep -Po '/users/\K[^/]+' file`? See [this online demo](https://ideone.com/QYlKgC)

Comment: `grep -Eo '/users/[^/[:blank:]]+' file | cut -d/ -f3` should work fine for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set the delimiter and do a literal match to second field and print the third.

```
$ awk -F/ '$2=="users"{print $3}'
```

Comment: Since I actually asked the question with `awk`, I am going to accept this one.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do this in single `awk` then use `match` function:

```
awk -v s="/users/" 'match($0, s "[^/[:blank:]]+") {
   print substr($0, RSTART+length(s), RLENGTH-length(s))
}' file
```

Or else this `grep + cut` will do the job:

```
grep -Eo '/users/[^/[:blank:]]+' file | cut -d/ -f
```

Comment: Thank you, I like the `grep` solution a lot, however as I asked the question with `awk` I accepted the other one being simpler...

Comment: Reason I proposed `match` approach because in question you mentioned extracting this string from a URL. So both of these solutions will also extract `USERNAME` from a URL e.g. `http://example.com/users/USERNAME/blabla/` but `awk -F/ '$2=="users"{print $3}'` won't.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your statement gives you the entire line of something like
`/users/USERNAME/garbage/otherStuff/`

You could pipe this result through head assuming you always know that it will be
`/users/USERNAME/....`

After piping through head, you can also use `cut` commands to remove more of the end text until you have only the piece you want.

> The command will look something like this 
> `awk '/users\/.*\//{print $0}' file | head (options) | cut (options)`